# How to interpret the explicit references to GNU in the LSB specifications?

Tags: gnu, standard, non-gnu, lsb

The LSB is a specification, and as such, should be provider neutral. But it contains many “hard‑coded” reference to GNU at many places. Ex. the ELF Linux's specific entries `PT_GNU_STACK`, `PT_GNU_RELRO` and al., or with some libraries like `libgcc_s`. How these explicit references to GNU in the LSB should be interpreted?

- Is it there for historical reasons (like the `MZ` magic in one of the Windows executable formats)?
- Is it there to designate GNU as a unique provider for some parts of conforming systems?
- Is it there as an acknowledgement of some role played (currently or in the paste) without any particular mandate?

I would not have asked this questions, if the references did not appeared in a standard specification, I mean, the questions should be understood in this particular context.

Comment: Provider neutral? No. `rpm` is part of LSB.

Comment: @jordanm and although I know very little about this standard... there is more than one rpm provider... Suse RPMS are not 100% compat with RHELs. Standards are for interop, but usually an implementation or prefereably two exist before the standard does.